# Microsoft Edge taking up too much space

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

My `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!001\MicrosoftEdge\History\mms` folder contains a huge 33GB of data.

Could anyone tell me what `mms` contains and whether is it safe to remove files from mms?

Answer (score 0):

According to a [comment to a German  blog](https://www.borncity.com/blog/2018/06/15/windows-10-edge-mllt-festplatte-zu/#comment-59441), this happens when you visit Facebook via Edge.

> I have the same problem only with IE and Facebook.  Under C: \ Users \
>   Andy \ AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Windows \ History \ History.IE5 \
>   mms  The folder is hidden and was 45 GB in size. But I discovered only
>   through the program TreeSize. In the end, I deleted it, **but it
>   re-creates itself as soon as I open the Facebook page. The folder
>   fills only through the Facebook page. If I do not go to the FB page,
>   then the folder does not create new and there are no entries**.

You can delete the data. To avoid this , use a different browser

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after listening to a large YouTube playlist. Edge seems to store media in this folder.

Clearing 'Browsing history' in the settings removed the folder and freed up space.